# Django: Can't access static files in python script

Tags: python, django, apache, static, mod-wsgi

I have **deployed a django project with mod wsgi on an apache server**. Everything works so far.
In one **python script** I'd like to **open a file in static files**.

Therefore I have tried something like this:

mycode.py

```
import cv2


    class Foo():
      def __init__(self):
        ...

      def openImg(self):
        self.myimg = cv2.imread('static/myapp/img/picture.jpg',0)
        return self.myimg
```

.. just for testing

**However it can't find this file.**

Whether in path ('static/myapp/img/picture.jpg'), nor path ('myapp/static/myapp/img/picture.jpg') nor in path ('../static/myapp/img/picture.jpg') and some other which I have already forgot.

It always returns "None".

If I try the same on my "undeployed" local project it works without any problem.

I have already collected all staticfiles to /myproject/static and given enough rights to access them.

**By the way, the access to the static files in the html works in production.**

What's the problem?
Can you give me any advice?

Thank you.

---

Some additional information:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .mycode import Foo

def index(request):

   # New Instance for class Foo
   bar = Foo()

   # Return img array to put it in html for whatever 
   imagearray = bar.openImg()

   context = {'imgarray': imgarray}
   return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

Thats an example of my directory

```
/home/myuser/MyProject
  /static/myapp/img/picture.jpg (collected)
  /
  /myapp
    /static/myapp/img/picture.jpg
    /mycode.py
    /views.py
  /MyProject
    /settings.py
```

In my apache config file:

```
Alias /static /home/myuser/MyProject/static
<Directory /home/myuser/MyProject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/myuser/MyProject/media 
<Directory /home/myuser/MyProject/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/myuser/MyProject/MyProject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myuser/MyProject/MyProject/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/myuser/MyProject python-home=/home/myuser/MyProject/venv
WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

Answer (score 0):

In mycode.py you might want to try:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
import cv2


    class Foo():
      def __init__(self):
        ...

      def openImg(self):
        path = staticfiles_storage.path('myapp/img/picture.jpg')
        self.myimg = cv2.imread(path,0)
        return self.myimg
```

Answer (score -2):

This was happening to me until i ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

could you try this?

Comment: I have already ran this. All files are collected in MyProject/static...